# Pass array with data values using POST payload with BackBone

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, backbone.js

Using BackBone i send both variables and array to post call to be sent to database. I was able to obtain the variables. But when i try to access array it goes to ERROR and unable to access that array also. Is this the way of sending is correct?

### AdminView.php

```
  addQuestion: function (event) {
    var question = $('#txtQuestion').val();
    var correctAns = $('#txtCorrectAns').val();
    var options = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
    var data = {question: question, catID: catID, correctAns: correctAns, options: options};
    Backbone.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        ansyc: false,
        url: "http://localhost/TEST/index.php/Rest_API/RestAPI/question",
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (val) {
            alert("Success");
        },
        error: function (erorr) {
            alert("Failed");
        }
    });
}
```

### RestAPI

```
function question_post() {
        $question = $this->post('question');
        $catID = $this->post('catID');
        $correctAns = $this->post('correctAns');
        $options = $this->post('options');

        $this->load->model('QuestionModel');
        $response = $this->QuestionModel->addQuestion($question,$catID,$correctAns);
        $this->response($response);
    }
```

Comment: I think this is more suitable for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: You're not using Backbone properly here, you are just using `Backbone.ajax` which is the same as doing `jQuery.ajax`. Put your data as attributes in a `Backbone.Model`, set a `url` property, and call `.fetch()` on your model instance - you can look at tutorials which cover this

Answer (score 0):

Use a model and use Model.save()

http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save